# How to distinguish regular organizations from non-profit ones with Google API?

Tags: java, google-api, google-admin-sdk, sku

We have an app that's getting license info about our clients' Google organizations. We've been using SKU IDs before but now we've faced with non-profit organization and Google support says there's no SKU IDs for nonprofits.

We've been investigating a way to use `ProductId` instead but I see no suitable `ProductIds` for non profits [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/how-tos/products)

For regular organizations we're using `com.google.api.services.licensing` Java package
and something like

```
var productLicensing = new Licensing.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, oAuth2Credentials)
    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
var request = productLicensing.licenseAssignments()
    .listForProductAndSku(productId, skuId, domain);
var assignments = request.execute();
// further operations
```

**Is there any idea how we can distinguish regular organizations from non-profit ones using Google API?** Do nonprofits have special `ProductId`?

Comment: Are you referring to [Google Workspace for nonprofits](https://support.google.com/nonprofits/answer/3367223)?

Comment: @iamblichus yes, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

I don't think there are product ids for Nonprofit licenses. Therefore, I don't think there's any API that will return this kind of information.

#### Feature requests:

I went ahead and filed a feature request in Issue Tracker to add `productIds` to Non-profit licenses:

- [Add productId for Nonprofit licenses](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230369510)

There's also a feature request to list all available products and SKUs. It might be useful in this kind of situations:

- [Google API Call for All Available Licenses and SKUs](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201559235)

Consider [subscribing to these issues](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to keep track of them and to help prioritizing them.